# jQuery multiple backgrounds from clicked elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble getting this to work. I'm currently working on an eCommerce project on the product page. On this page, I have the main product image and two additional rows of images from which a user can choose so that he can be able to view the main image with different backgrounds.

The way this works is I need to get the #actual_image_url (which is the actual size of the photo I need to overlay) and either add it using multiple backgrounds, or using innerHTML adding it inside the div of the main image.

Basically, I've added so far an event listener for the click event on that DIV and I've been experimenting with pushing the 'data-target' attribute to an array. I figured if I could store the actual 'data-target' URLS in an array and pop the last two, that should do it. It didn't, so I'm asking for help :)

```
<div class="image_options">

<!-- first row of images -->
<a href="#"><img src="#small_image_url" id="option-value-47" data-target="#actual_image_url"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#small_image_url" id="option-value-48" data-target="#actual_image_url"></a>

<!-- second row of images -->

<a href="#"><img src="#small_image_url" id="option-value-147" data-target="#actual_image_url"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#small_image_url" id="option-value-148" data-target="#actual_image_url"></a>

</div>
```

jQuery code so far:

```
var contentImageUrl = [];
$(selector).on("click", function(event) {       
            event.preventDefault();     
            contentImageUrl.push(event.srcElement.getAttribute('data-target'));
```

User should be clicking on either one of two second rows of pictures, so I need the data-attribute for both of them. I also need a way to add these as backgrounds to the main image after I've fetched the 'data-target' URL.

please help guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for JQuery.data(): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

In addition, you can use $(this) to refer to the element that was clicked.

```
contentImageUrl.push($(this).data("target"));
```

Comment: If I were to provide the project URL, do you think you would be able to help with some sample code ? I've looked into jquery.data() before I posted this question and I'm still not able to figure it out, unfortunately.

Comment: There's some sample code; I should have done that to start with.  It's also worth noting that there are a plethora of jQuery plugins to do this sort of thing, so you may want to look into that, too.